# put login and password in one table or in multiple tables for each type of user?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have different 3 types of users and each type of user can have columns and relationships with tables that another type doesn't, but all of them have login(Unique) and password, 
how would you do:

- create a table for each type or
- create one table for all of them or
- create a table for all of them only for login and password and separate for all the other things and bind them with a FK
- something else

Comment: I'd say it depends :) Is there anything else they share? Do you want to display them on one page? Can users be "transferred"? Can the same user exist with two types?

Comment: yes, they also may share FirstName, LastName, etc. One user cannot exist with two types. Don't know what you mean by transferred, so I guess not :).

Comment: put everything they share in the same table. See the table on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Answer (score 11):

Number 3 is the best of the options you suggested (updated slightly for clarification):

- create a table for all of them for login and password *and anything else that is shared* and a separate table for all the other things that are not shared and bind them with a FK

Except don't store the password, store a hashed version of a salted password.

An alternative might be to assign groups and/or roles to your users. This might be more flexible than a fixed table structure, allowing you to add new roles dynamically. But it depends on your needs whether this is useful for you or not.

As Aaronaught pointed out, in the main table you need an `AccountType` to ensure that a user can only have one of the roles. You **must** remember to check the value of this column when joining the tables to ensure that a user has only one role active.

A unique constraint on the foreign key ensures that a user can only have a role once.

Comment: one thing with this option is that there is no constraint to stop two rows from 2 different user types tables to reference the same row in in the "login_password" table

Comment: @Omu: Put a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column in each FK table, and use a discriminator column (`AccountType`) in the main table.  You should have the discriminator anyway, it's critical for efficiency (and Mark, I think you should add this).

Comment: @Aaronaught: Good point. When I originally posted my answer wasn't clear that each user could only have one role, but I can see that now from Omu's comments.

Comment: @Aaronaught could you explain that, if i have this schema:     Account(AccountID, login, password, UserType(this is char cuz i need to know the usertype for this account))      UserType1(id, AccountID, ...)         UserType2(id, AccountID,...)  how do you do what you said ?

Comment: how is the AccountType in the main table going to prevent a user from having multiple roles ? this doesn't create a constraint

Comment: @Omu: Excellent question! The answer is perhaps not obvious, so I'll put this into my post: When you join, check the account type as part of the join condition. Don't just check if the user exists in the table.

Comment: so the Unique key constraint on each column AccountID FK from the UserTypes Tables ensures that a UserType can reference one Account and the join condition will help to obtain zero rows from the UserTypes table which is not of the specified AccountType, but it is still possible to insert  ONE row in each UserType table that is going to reference same row in Account table, although if we write the join with the AccountType condition we aren't going to get the bad data from the DB

Comment: Omu: Yes, you can insert the row but it will never be fetched if the AccountType is incorrect.

Comment: I did it like this: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx